# pg_dumpall missing = in connection string

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run pg_dumpall on an AWS RDS instance (postgres).
I tried to connect to the db by using psql:

```
psql -d $DBNAME -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $USERNAME
```

I'm of course prompt for password and everything works fine - I'm able to connect.

I then tried:

```
pg_dumpall.exe -d $DBNAME -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $USERNAME -f testme.sql
```

I get the following error:

```
pg_dumpall: missing "=" after "billingdb" in connection info string
```

I'm using git bash as my terminal, I'm on windows 10, my psql version is 9.6.4
The connection itself is done via port forwarding so my host is localhost and some port that the port_forwarding action provide if that matters.
According to the documentation I'm doing everything right so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 13):

The option `-d` means something else in `psql` and in `pg_dumpall`. The `pg_dumpall` documentation says:

> `-d connstr`
>   `--dbname=connstr`
>
> Specifies parameters used to connect to the server, as a connection string. See Section 32.1.1 for more information.
>
> The option is called `--dbname` for consistency with other client applications, but because `pg_dumpall` needs to connect to many databases, database name in the connection string will be ignored. Use `-l` option to specify the name of the database used to dump global objects and to discover what other databases should be dumped.

My advice is to just omit that option, then the database `postgres` is used as it should.

Comment: Thanks for that, still not working though and now I'm wondering if it's something from AWS side.
I did (assuming I understood correctly) `pg_dumpall.exe --dbname=postgres://root@localhost:59082 -l mydb`
again the localhost and odd port is because I'm forced to do port forwarding to communicate with the instance, the error message I get is:
`pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "mydb"` and on the port forward terminal I see `incoming request to ... failed: SSHException('SSH session not active',)`

Comment: ok I started a new connection which solved the above, but now getting:
`PostgreSQL database cluster dump
SET default_transaction_read_only = off;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT oid, rolname, rolsuper, rolinherit, rolcreaterole, rolcreatedb, rolcanlogin, rolconnlimit, rolpassword, rolvaliduntil, rolreplication, rolbypassrls.....`
what does `permission denied for relation` mean? I'm using the root user

Comment: You have to use a PostgreSQL database superuser to get this to work. Try the option `-U postgres`.